# How to read multiple directories which have different number of files into tensorflow dataset

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

My tensorflow version is 1.15, and my directory tree is depicted below.

```
root
|
|---scene1
|     |
|     |--img1.npy
|     |--img2.npy
|     |--cam.txt
|     |--poses.txt
|
|---scene2
|     |
|     |--img1.npy
|     |--img2.npy
|     |--img3.npy
|     |--cam.txt
|     |--poses.txt
```

Each scene folder contains different number of images(in npy format), but exactly one cam.txt and one poses.txt. I have tried that using `numpy.genfromtxt` and `numpy.load` to read files in each scene folder into tensor, then using

`ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors` to create dataset for each scene, finally using `ds.concatenate` to concatenate these datasets. This method works, but waste a lot of time when the number of scene folders goes huge. Is there any better way to handle the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I recently ran into a similar problem.

When dealing with very large datasets, Python [generators](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#generators) are a good option to go:

> [Generators] are written like regular functions but use the yield statement whenever they want to return data. Each time `next()` is called on it, the generator resumes where it left off (it remembers all the data values and which statement was last executed).

Tensorflow's `Dataset` class supports them with the static [`from_generator`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#from_generator) method (also available [with TF 1.15](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.15/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#from_generator)):

```py
import pathlib
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

def scene_generator():
    base_dir = pathlib.Path('path/to/root/')
    scenes = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(str(base_dir / '*'))
    for s in scenes:
        scene_dir = pathlib.Path(s.numpy().decode('utf-8'))
        images = scene_dir / '*.npy'
        data = []
        for i in images:
            with np.load(i) as image:
                features = [image['x1'], image['x2']] # ...
                data.append(features)
        cam   = np.genfromtxt(scene_dir / 'cam.txt')
        poses = np.genfromtxt(scene_dir / 'poses.txt')

        yield data, [cam, poses]

types = (tf.float32, tf.float32)
shapes = (tf.TensorShape([None]), tf.TensorShape([2, None]))
train_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(scene_generator,
    output_types=types,
    output_shapes=shapes)
```

Comment: Thanks, and I have another question. How about the running time of generator, compare to reading TFRecord and torch.utils.data.DataLoader?

Comment: I have no experience with PyTorch yet. But what do you mean exactly by "running  time"?

Comment: The time to iterate over whole dataset. Is reading TFRecord(already converted from those directories) faster than python generator(reading from raw directory trees)?

Comment: Yes, I guess reading a single binary .tfrecord file would be faster than reading multiple .npy files.